# How to assign one class type instance to another class type reference in swift to apply dynamic polymorphism

Tags: swift2

iam unable to set backgroundcolor for label at runtime

```
func example() {
  let lbl: UILabel = UILabel()
  let arrTemp: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
  arrTemp.addObject(lbl)
  let tempButton: UIButton? = arrTemp.objectAtIndex(0) as? UIButton
  tempButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
```

Comment: you wrote: "iam unable to set backgroundcolor for label at runtime". Did you try it? may i know, why did you try to cast UILabel as UIButton? do you think, that this is 'dynamic polymorphism'?

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is wrong for several reasons.
Let's see what you are doing

1. You are adding a `UILabel` to `arrTemp`.

   ```
   arrTemp.addObject(lbl)
   ```

Now `arrTemp` does contain `UILabel` as only element

2. Next you retrieve the first element of arrTemp and try to cast it as `UIButton`.

   ```
   let tempButton: UIButton? = arrTemp.objectAtIndex(0) as? UIButton
   ```

Of course the conditional cast will always fail (given the current code) and tempButton will be populated with `nil`.

3. You are accessing a property of tempButton (which is an Optional Value) without unwrapping it. The Swift compiled does not allow you to do this.

   ```
   tempButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
   ```
4. You could update the last line to make the compiler happy

   ```
   tempButton?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
   ```

but the last assignment will never be executed since `tempButton` will always be `nil`.

Now a question: what are you trying to do? What do you want to achieve putting a `UILabel` into an array and then trying to use that label as a `UIButton`?

Answer (score 0):

You can only reference the object as something it actually is.  Otherwise, you could ask a label for its `buttonType` by using your untyped array without getting a compile-time error.

If you don't want that form of type safety, Objective-C is probably a better choice.

Comment: I don't agree with your sentence: `If you don't want that form of type safety, Objective-C is probably a better choice.`. If some code is wrong, using a less restrictive compiler does not solve the problem, it just let you compile conceptually wrong code :-)

Comment: @appzYourLife  I don't think the sentence is wrong so much as it's an acceptance of the fact that some people like dynamic languages.  If the code is actually wrong, it will get caught either way.  (Personally, I'd like the compiler to catch it but that doesn't seem to be true for everyone.)

Answer (score 0):

A `UILabel` is a subclass of `UIView`; a `UIView` has a settable property of `backgroundColor`.  So, to set a `UILabel` color use simply:

```
func example() {
  let lbl: UILabel = UILabel()
  lbl.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
  // do something with lbl.
}
```